# Convert PDF to Word in C# or VB without third party tools

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# - pdf to word programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083387/c-sharp-pdf-to-word-programmatically)
>   [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

I want to convert PDF to Word in C# or VB. How I can convert? 
Is ItextSharp is helpful for this purpose?
Or any other way to find out the solution.

> I don't want to use third party tools

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't want to use third party tool to convert pdf to word, don't mark it as duplicate pleas

Comment: @RobertHarvey  please reopen my question

Comment: You can't do this conversion without using some sort of third-party library, unless you want to spend a year coding up a decent solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That'w why I post question here as I want to start an application that will do the same, but I need the basic to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of 3rd part libraries to do this, one of them is ItextSharp but you can use other tols like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) or using installed addins like this example: [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

Comment: First thing I do not want to convert doc to pdf, I want to convert pdf to word, and second thing aspose is not free tool, am I right?

Comment: ur right! its not free but iTextsharp is free

Comment: But in itextSharp, is there any way to do this

Comment: k I google, why Robert make my question duplicate

Comment: This is a good question maby cause its duplicate :) c links

Comment: Can we convert pdf to HTML and then HTML to doc or either pdf to XML and then XML to doc